# How to join two SQL Server tables which have no common column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables in SQL Server and I need my output as below.

Table 1:

| nParaID | cParaNo | cParaYear | cParaCD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 219 | 1 | 2021 | VTMC |
| 220 | 1 | 2021 | SFCC |

Table 2:

| cFtyCD | cInvNo |
| --- | --- |
| VTM | VTM0001/S/20 |
| SFC | SFC001/30 |

Final result should be ,

| nParaID | cParaNo | cParaYear | cParaCD | cFtyCD | cInvNo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 219 | 1 | 2021 | VTMC | VTM | VTM0001/S/20 |
| 220 | 1 | 2021 | SFCC | SFC | SFC001/30 |

Can someone please tell me how to get final result?

Comment: So **how do you know** to combine the `nParaId=219` part with the `cFtyCD=VTM` part in table #2 ?? Why does it have to be this way - couldn't it be combined with the second row in the #2 table?? Also: what defines the **order** of these rows in those two tables, if you want to combine the "first" from both tables, then the "second" - what's the **ordering criteria** (seeing that relational database tables are **inherently unordered** sets of data)?

Comment: I need , to get cParaCD=cFtyCD and join these two tables.

Comment: In your example you never have cParaCD=cFtyCD (cParaCD ends with a D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So , your cParaCD column from table1 have first 3 characters equal to your column cFtyCD from Table2. If this criteria (which is evident from the sample data shared by you for both tables) remains same for all your rows in first and second table then below query can be used.

I am essentially taking out first 3 characters from cParaCD and then equating them to value in column cFtyCD.

```
Select
nParaID ,  cParaNo    ,cParaYear    ,cParaCD    ,cFtyCD    ,cInvNo
from Table1 a 
join Table2 b on substring(a.cParaCD,1,len(b.cFtyCD)) = b.cFtyCD
```

Answer (score 0):

What I got to know from the above example is both the tables have the same number of rows and they need to be joined side-ways without any common join-key.
To achieve this create a temporary column with a common join key and then apply a join. The join_key is generated using a row_number with ordering on a literal.

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 100)) AS join_key, t.* FROM your_table1 t) AS t1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 100)) AS join_key, t.* FROM your_table2 t) AS t2
ON t1.join_key = t2.join_key
```

PS: This is just for curiosity. It is not at all a good practice to join the SQL tables like this without any proper join key.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the most common column is cParaCD of table 1 and cFtyCD of table 2 you can use 'like' on inner join instead of '='

```
select * from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2
on t1.cParaCD like CONCAT('%',t2.cFtyCD, '%');
```

Comment: The requirements are not clear, so there's no reason to use a leading wildcard which is non-sargable.